# Extra Button in Accordion/Collapsible

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need an extra button in my collapsible. But if I insert one in the heading the heading text is misplaced. how can I center all elements (icon, text and button)?

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
    <h4>
        Heading
<a id="fetch-data" href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true">Check</a>
    </h4>
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mkeuschn/z0aw0o4v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a better solution is to remove the button from the current document flow and position it absolute.

Use the following css:

```
#fetch-data {
    top: 4px !important;
    right: 6px;
    position: absolute;
}
```